# Сounter of digits after decimal point (double)

Tags: c, math, double, counter

Pls, help with this problem. I need to count the number of digits after the decimal point. But when *f* should be *0* it becomes *1* and *i* becomes *2* (but should be *3*).
After the code, the output from the console

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>       

int main()
{
  double i;
  double f;
  int count = 0;
  double eps = 10.123;

  while(f!=0){
  f = modf(eps, &i);
  printf("%f \n%f\n", i, f);
  count = count + 1;
  i=0;
  eps=f*10;
  printf("%f\n\n", eps);
  }
  printf("Count = %d", count);

    return 0;
}
```

10.000000
0.123000
1.230000

1.000000
0.230000
2.300000

2.000000
0.300000
3.000000

2.000000
1.000000
10.000000

9.000000
1.000000
10.000000

9.000000
1.000000
10.000000

9.000000
1.000000
10.000000

9.000000
1.000000
10.000000

9.000000
1.000000
9.999999

9.000000
0.999999
9.999993

9.000000
0.999993
9.999933

9.000000
0.999933
9.999332

9.000000
0.999332
9.993321

9.000000
0.993321
9.933209

9.000000
0.933209
9.332090

9.000000
0.332090
3.320898

3.000000
0.320898
3.208983

3.000000
0.208983
2.089828

2.000000
0.089828
0.898284

0.000000
0.898284
8.982839

8.000000
0.982839
9.828386

9.000000
0.828386
8.283855

8.000000
0.283855
2.838551

2.000000
0.838551
8.385506

8.000000
0.385506
3.855058

3.000000
0.855058
8.550583

8.000000
0.550583
5.505825

5.000000
0.505825
5.058253

5.000000
0.058253
0.582528

0.000000
0.582528
5.825281

5.000000
0.825281
8.252811

8.000000
0.252811
2.528114

2.000000
0.528114
5.281143

5.000000
0.281143
2.811432

2.000000
0.811432
8.114319

8.000000
0.114319
1.143188

1.000000
0.143188
1.431885

1.000000
0.431885
4.318848

4.000000
0.318848
3.188477

3.000000
0.188477
1.884766

1.000000
0.884766
8.847656

8.000000
0.847656
8.476562

8.000000
0.476562
4.765625

4.000000
0.765625
7.656250

7.000000
0.656250
6.562500

6.000000
0.562500
5.625000

5.000000
0.625000
6.250000

6.000000
0.250000
2.500000

2.000000
0.500000
5.000000

5.000000
0.000000
0.000000

Count = 50

Comment: 10.123 is actually : `10.1229999999999993320898283855058252811431884765625`  https://godbolt.org/z/7Tha1cor9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you assigned `10.123` to the variable does not mean that is ***exactly*** what got stored there.

Floating point representations are only approximate (although they do have very high precision)

`10.123` cannot be precisely stored, and the binary approximation is `10.1229999999...`, as shown by this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double x = 10.123;
    
    printf("%3.3f is stored as %3.20f\n", x, x);
    return 0;
}
```

### Output:

```
10.123 is stored as 10.12299999999999933209
```

### In otherwords, your code is working properly.

Comment: rather `10.1229999999999993320898283855058252811431884765625`

Comment: Is there any way to count the number of digits after the decimal point?

Comment: Yes.  Do it as a string before creating the inexact floating point variable.